# Extracting information from website

Tags: php, web-scraping, extract

I need to get the schedules of each class from this list: http://timeplan.uia.no/swsuiakrh/public/en/default.aspx

Is there an easy way to do it? I have heard of datamining but i have no idea what it is, any good tutorials for it?

Comment: This isn't data-mining - this is web scraping. cURL is fine, or there are loads of specific packages for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) to fetch the page and then use something like [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to get the exact data that you want.